# CGAL Program (and Examples) Not Getting Compiled in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: macos, cgal

**System Info:** Mac OS x 10.7

> CGAL installed in: CGAL INCLUDES are in /opt/local/include/CGAL/ CGAL
>   LIBRARIES are in /opt/local/lib/cmake
>
> CGAL INFO: singhg@~/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2$ port search
>   cgal cgal @3.9 (gis, science)
>       Computational Geometry Algorithm Library
>
> singhg@~/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2$ port deps cgalFull
>   Name: cgal @3.9_0 Build Dependencies:   cmake Library Dependencies:
>   boost, mpfr, zlib, gmp
>
> CMAKE INFO: singhg@~/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2$ port search
>   cmake cmake @2.8.6 (devel)
>       Cross-platform make
>
> gccmakedep @1.0.2 (x11, devel)
>       Create dependencies in makefiles using 'gcc -M'
>
> Found 2 ports.

**HERE IS MY QUERY:**

Now I downloaded examples of CGAL_3.9 and tried to run Triangulation_2 using Xcode. Below is the output I got. (I also tried to run Voronoi_diagram_2 example but it has the same problems)

1) Terminal command **cmake -GXcode** into the directory

> /Users/singhg/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2

But it says:

> singhg@~/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2$ cmake -GXcode
>   -- The C compiler identification is GNU
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
>   -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
>   -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
>   -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
>   -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
>   -- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode
>   -- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode -- works
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>   -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
>   -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
>   -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
>   -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode -- works
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
>   -- This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.
>   -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: /Users/singhg/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2
>
> **-- This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be
>   compiled.**
>   
>   2) I again tried to follow this link http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Getting-started-with-CGAL-on-a-mac-OS-X-td3171984.html and in my system the CGALConfig.cmake file is in **/opt/local/lib/cmake** So I tried this command on my bash Terminal:
>
> cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/opt/local/lib/cmake

And Here is the output:

> singhg@~/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2$ cmake
>   -DCGAL_DIR=/opt/local/lib/cmake CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (include):   include could not find load file:
>
> ```
> /opt/local//opt/local/lib/cmake/UseCGAL.cmake
> ```
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (include):   include could not find
>   load file:
>
> ```
> CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram
> ```
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (create_single_source_cgal_program): 
>   Unknown CMake command "create_single_source_cgal_program".
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   
>   3) I tried again with
>
> cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/opt/local/lib/CCGAL

But it was stupid coz there is no CGAL dir in  `/opt/local/lib/` but it is in `/opt/local/lib/cmake`.

Here is the output I got from this attempt:

> singhg@~/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2$ cmake
>   -DCGAL_DIR=/opt/local/lib/CGAL
>   -- This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.
>   -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: /Users/singhg/Programming/examples/Triangulation_2
>   
>   4) I again tried with CMAKE GUI (2.8.6 version) and here on "Configure" I got:
>
> The C compiler identification is GNU The CXX compiler identification
>   is GNU Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot Checking whether C
>   compiler has -isysroot - yes Checking whether C compiler supports OSX
>   deployment target flag Checking whether C compiler supports OSX
>   deployment target flag - yes Check for working C compiler:
>   /usr/bin/gcc Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
>   Detecting C compiler ABI info Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>   Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot Checking whether CXX
>   compiler has -isysroot - yes Checking whether CXX compiler supports
>   OSX deployment target flag Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX
>   deployment target flag - yes Check for working CXX compiler:
>   /usr/bin/c++ Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
>   Detecting CXX compiler ABI info Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
>   This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.
>   Configuring done

And when I tried to fix the error by specifying CGAL_DIR to **/opt/local/lib/cmake** where CGALConfig.cmake lies. It gives these errors:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (include):   include could not find
>   load file:
>
> ```
> /opt/local//opt/local/lib/cmake/UseCGAL.cmake
> ```
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (include):   include could not find
>   load file:
>
> ```
> CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram
> ```
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (create_single_source_cgal_program): 
>   Unknown CMake command "create_single_source_cgal_program".
>
> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

These examples are not been able to find where the CGAL Libraries are. If someone Can help then please help. I cannot find a way to compile any of my CGAL Program.

Thank you
bagga

Comment: Please help guys if you are working on CGAL in Mac OS X 10.7(.2). I have spend many hours in trying to debug this "simple stuff"

Comment: any chance, you tried something like this on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)? I am having issues compiling some of the examples since I upgraded (e.g. Surface_reconstruction_points_3 does not compile).

Comment: Sorry Chris, I am still using 10.7.x OS X version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this link for the answer:

[Compiling a basic CGAL program in C++ on Mac OS X 10.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404968/compiling-a-basic-cgal-program-in-c-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2)

Or this one:

http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Compiling-a-basic-CGAL-program-in-C-on-Mac-OS-X-10-7-2-td4166413.html#a4387321